# React Context & Typescript with Custom Hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I have created the following context provider using React & Chakra-UI:

```
import { useBoolean } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import { createContext } from "react"

const MobileContext = createContext<typeof useBoolean | undefined>(undefined)

function MobileProvider({ children }) {
  const [show, setShow] = useBoolean(false)

  return (
    <MobileContext.Provider value={{ show, setShow }}>
      {children}
    </MobileContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Unfortunately, the above code does not seem to work.  I get a red squiggly line under `show` in `value={{ show, setShow }}` with the following message:

```
Type '{ 
  show: boolean; 
  setShow: { 
    readonly on: () => void; 
    readonly off: () => void;  
    readonly toggle: () => void; 
  }; 
}' is not assignable to type 
  '(initialState?: InitialState) => 
  readonly [
      boolean, 
      { 
        readonly on: () => void; 
        readonly off: () => void; 
        readonly toggle: () => void; 
      }
   ]'.
  

Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'show' does not exist in type 

  '(initialState?: InitialState) => 
    readonly [
      boolean, 
      { 
        readonly on: () => void; 
        readonly off: () => void; 
        readonly toggle: () => void; 
      }
   ]'
   .ts(2322)
   index.d.ts(336, 9): 

The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 
  'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<(initialState?: InitialState) => 
    readonly [
      boolean, 
      { 
         readonly on: () => void; 
         readonly off: () => void; 
         readonly toggle: () => void; 
      }
    ]
  >'
```

I think I understand what the problem is -- that the return value of `useBoolean` is not exactly the same as `show` and `setShow` (although perhaps I am wrong).  Either way, I can't figure out how to get this to work properly.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are providing the *return value* of `useBoolean`, and you shape the context value differently, you should
replace

```
const MobileContext = createContext<typeof useBoolean | undefined>(undefined)
```

With

```
type UseBooleanReturn = ReturnType<typeof useBoolean>

const MobileContext = createContext<{show: UseBooleanReturn[0], setShow: UseBooleanReturn[1] } | undefined>(undefined)
```